# MVVM-Light WP7 - swap views on VM or access previous VM instead of navigate querystring params?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, viewmodel, mvvm-light

Is there a way to simply swap between different views using the same view-model?

I'd like to be able to let the user navigate to different views of the same view model.

Based on the examples I've found so far, I'm using a navigation service to switch between views, passing in an ID to the URI, so that the target VM knows what record to load.

The different renderings are accomplished through helper conversion objects bound on the XAML so the VMs are basically a thin wrapper around the model and some navigation functionality.

A different approach to navigation would be to have the different renderings on the same view and collapse the unused views until they are used but that would make the view much more complex and would take the different renderings out of the navigation stack.

Since the VM is almost identical between views it would seem to make more sense to just swap out the views rather than to store/reload the object based on IDs.

The operating assumption is that you need a separate VM for each view, or at least a separate instance of a VM for each view, and each VM has no access to the context of the previous VM except what is passed through on the navigate query string params.

To recap:
1) Can I swap views on a VM with navigate without losing data context?

or
2) Can I get access to the previous VM on a navigate to event?

Update:
More info 
->) From the Mix11 Deep Dive Navigation sample - retrieve the VM from SimpleIOC using ID passed on the nav query as the key and set the DataContext to it. This is similar to storing / retrieving the data object in storage and retrieving it based on the key. This is in the OnNavigated event handler in the target page codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple views do not need separate instances of the ViewModel, you can quite happliy share the same ViewModel (e.g. a singleton) between multiple views. However, you have to be aware that changing the properties of this shared ViewModel affects the other Views as well.

In addition you could also hold your Model as a Singleton and let multiple ViewModels bind to this instance.

So for your questions:

1. You will have to navigate to a View but this can be bound to a singleton ViewModel.
2. Well depends, if all your ViewModels are singletons you can. But do you want it? Personally I think it is better to share the Model then.